# File Directory and File Creation Problems

Tags: java, file

I have problems with the following code. I am trying to look at an existing directory to see if a file exists before creating a new one, but it doesnt seem to create a new file even though there are no existing ones in the directory. I have attached the two relevant methods, but the problem lies with the `writeFile()` method. I tried to use the existing 'dir' in writeFile, this didnt do the trick either. The rest of the program does seem to work, just the `writeFile` method has problems.

```
public void writeFile(String t) throws IOException {
    File temp1 = new File(dateNow + File.separator + "Temperature.txt");
    boolean check = temp1.exists();
    if (!check)
        newFiles();
}

public void newFiles() {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    dateNow = formatter.format(now.getTime());
    System.out.println(dateNow);
    // if (hour == 00 && mini == 00 && sec == 00) {
    try {
        dir = new File(dateNow);
        boolean x = dir.mkdir();
        // ....
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete code

Comment: Nowhere in your code are you creating a file. You requested to create a ***subdirectory*** in the current folder (the one your program is executing in), but you didn't check the boolean return of that operation to see if it succeeded or not. Also, you need to do something with your exceptions, you should never just swallow them the way your code is showing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify the full path, not just the directory and the file name to create a file or even check it's existence,.
thank you for michael667, you remind me about the relative position is right,. :)
and there should be no problem with the above code,.

Comment: That's not true. A relative path is relative to the current working directory.

Comment: how do u check directory and not a file?

Comment: it works when compiled from desktop but in folder it didnt work?

Comment: to check if an instance of File is a directory, use the isDirectory() method.